# How much does heat pipe need to touch cpu

Tags: cpu, cooling, heatsink

I'm adding a shim to my laptop CPU because it doesn't seem like the heat pipes are making contact.

The shim I have isn't wide enough to cover the entire die.

I'm wondering, is this OK if I just have it in the middle, or should I put two shims next to eachother? There will be overhang if I do that.

[image]

This is a razor blade 2014 edition. I'm doing this because it's overheating and shutting of. I have two identical laptops of this model with the same problem.

Comment: Ok. No offense, but if you’re asking this question we might question the entire premise of what you are trying to accomplish. Why is it you think the heat pipes aren’t making contact? The more surface area in contact with the CPU the better. Sometimes the heat pipe mounting brackets require a little tweak to apply pressure evenly across the CPU. But adding a shim? This is a major change from the manufacturer specs and is almost certain to not improve anything. It sounds like an idea that has been floating around on the internet a long time with no real scientific basis.

Comment: Performing a load test while monitoring temperatures is typically enough to allow you to push on each mounting bracket a bit to see if one needs to be retensioned to distribute the load more evenly across the surface of the laptop. You can also clearly see where contact is made and where it is not made in the new thermal paste impression.

Comment: @Appleoddity Sure. This wasn't my first attempt at solving this problem. I've repasted and tweaked the heat pipes 6 times at this point. Doing a stress test with XTU pushes the CPU temp into the 90's, and that's an improvement over how it was. In this instance it seems the manufacture just did a shit job with their design. Since it's a laptop I'm doing what I can with what they gave me.

Comment: Laptops historically have poor thermal performance. I can understand wanting to have it run as cool as you can and there may be some small tweaks, like retensioning the mounting bracket arms, but for the most part CPUs run hotter in laptops. If it’s a high end CPU, 90s for temp under full load is not unreasonable. I’ve seen it many times. Adding a shim is not likely to improve anything, and it could actually damage something especially when laptops have such tight tolerances in their design. Btw, sometimes the heat pipe does not make contact with both chips, by design.

Comment: I'm trying to fix the laptop shutdown down due to overheating. The specs on the CPU show that it's limit is 100c, which it does hit currently and the computer will shut off completely.

Comment: I've applied two shims(side by side) and paste and I'm 12c cooler now.

Comment: That makes sense. It would help to post your make and model of computer so others can research or share their experience with it.

Comment: Good news it’s getting better. I did some research, there are a lot of complaints about overheating razers. I see it’s not a good design from this post: https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/902551-razer-blade-14-2014-heat-issues/?tab=comments#comment-11111964

Comment: Yup that's the one lol.

Comment: I will say, under a stress test for 10 minutes, the fans only turned on high for maybe 10 seconds in the middle, where as they'd be on for most of the run before. It definitely helped. Didn't solve my issue with the machine powering off in some circumstances though. Now that I've ruled out thermals I think it maybe the power supply or battery.